# Lustre hangs while mounting oss

Tags: lustre

I have installed Parallel file system "Lustre" along with [this slide](http://cdn.opensfs.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Lustre-101_Andrus.pdf) with RPM.

Have set node A, B.

1. Installed mds and mdt to node A. Its mount was successful.
2. But, After format oss to node B using mkfs.lustre, then I mounted it, but it began **Infinite waiting**.
   And it retrieve this error once 120 seconds.

   INFO: task mount.lustre:1541 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
         Not tainted 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6_lustre.x86_64 #1
   "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

Why it occurs? Or can you give me better tutorial or experience? Its version of Lustre is 2.7.0.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is a info message. As mentioned in the message, though you can echo 0 to "hung_task_timeout_secs" to disable the message from showing up but still I will not recommend it.

Try to lower the mark for flushing the cache from 40% to 10% by setting “vm.dirty_ratio=5″ & "vm.dirty_background_ratio=5" in /etc/sysctl.conf. Activate it by using sysctl -p command, there is no need to reboot the system.